# How To Change Wordpress REST API date into "time ago" format

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Relatively new to using the Wordpress REST API. Learning as I code and have been reading tons of forums and tutorials, I've managed to code this get for a custom post type.

**My issue is trying to get the ISO8601 timestamp to render as "*xx* ago**".

I've looked into [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) & tried [TimeAgo](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin; but not sure I'm understanding the languages correctly to apply the functions to my current code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
 <div id="wodfeed"></div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/memberworkouts',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function (data) { 
    $(data).each(function(index, value) {
      var jtitle = value.title.rendered;
      var jimg = value.featured_image;
      var jid = value.member_id;
      var jtime=value.modified;

      $('#wodfeed').append('<div><h3 id="prog_date"><time class="timeago" datetime="' + jtime + '"> ' + jtime + ' </time></h3><h1 class="member-id">@' + jid + '</h1><img class="memberwod" src="'+ jimg +'"><h2 class="post-title"><span class="namebefore">' + jid + ' completed: </span> ' + jtitle + '</h2></div>');
    });
  }
});</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `moment(jtime).fromNow()`?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516548/how-to-convert-date-and-time-to-timeago-format-in-jquery

Comment: @AswinKumar This worked. Thank you. I had to reread some coding material on understanding variables. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @AswinKumar using Moments.js

Pass as a new variable:

```
moment(jtime).fromNow()
```

Then call the new variable in the append

```
 success: function (data) { 
    $(data).each(function(index, value) {
      var jtitle = value.title.rendered;
      var jimg = value.featured_image;
      var jid = value.member_id;
      var jtime=value.modified;
      var jtimeago= moment(jtime).fromNow(); 



      $('#wodfeed').append('<div><h3 id="prog_date">' + jtimeago + '</h3><h1 class="member-id">@' + jid + '</h1><img class="memberwod" src="'+ jimg +'"><h2 class="post-title"><span class="namebefore">' + jid + ' completed: </span> ' + jtitle + '</h2></div>');
    });
```